# Trying to get json from mercadolibre api but always gets the same cors error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, cross-domain

I am trying to consume a mercadolibre API that returns a json with some data that I need to use.

But everytime I tried by an ajax GET request it returns the same error:

**"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status"**

[image]

I Think it is a CORS issue, but I have tried everything on headers while the request (which is corssed domain) and nothing seems to work.

**Here is the way I am doing the ajax request:**

```
   if (obtieneCotizaciones == 'true' && token != null) {
    var sellerID = '499777238';
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://api.mercadolibre.com/quotations?access_token="+token+"&seller.id="+sellerID+"&caller.type=seller",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,        
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS',
          'Access-Control-Max-Age': '604800',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with'         
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);

        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log(error)
          console.log("FAIL");
        }
      });
  }
```

Any Idea how could I solve this? don't mind for 'token' and 'obtieneCotizaciones' variables, they are just needed to make the request and I obtein them before doing the request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing all of the headers? They are triggering a pre-flight which is why it's failing with that error.

Comment: he will always preflight with developer console opened.